# Matplotlib: Horizontal Linelength in Legend

Tags: matplotlib

Lets say i'm plotting a line with matplotlib and add a legend.
Within the legend it says `------ Label`. I find the default horizontal length of this line a bit too long when plotting small figure sizes for print.

Is there a property to set `------ Label` to `--- Label`?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

When you create your legend add the `handlelength` keyword  [(doc)](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend) which sets the length of the '---' (which is called the handle).

Comment: To complete: this typically comes as
`plt.legend(handlelength=4)`
if you want to increase from the default (2) to another value.
This comes handy if the marker conflicts with the linestyle, making it unreadable.